# How do I translate "all and only" and "if and only if"?

Tags: logic

Hi is the translation for "if and only if" (iif) the same as "All and only" i.e. both requires the bicondtional?

Comment: Yebs, "if and only if" is the bi-conditional (also: "exactly when").

Comment: "All and only" sounds a little bit weird: iff is used with sentences.

Comment: A if and only if B will be A ↔ B. All and only Ps are Qs will be ∀x (P(x) ↔ Q(x)).

Answer (score 5):

Standard translations for each do require the biconditional.

We translate "P, **if** Q" as "Q -> P"
We translate "P **only if** Q" as "P -> Q"
So when we combine "P, **if** Q" **and** "P **only if** Q" we get "P <-> Q"

We translate "All As are Bs" as "ALL(x)(Ax -> Bx)"
We translate "Only As are Bs" as "ALL(x)(Bx -> Ax)"
So when we combine "All As are Bs" **and** "Only As are Bs" we get "ALL(x)(Ax <-> Bx)"